# What CSS feature would you use to show elevation on a 2D grid?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to port an out of print board game that I used to play while growing up, and I'm trying to determine the best graphical method to display on a 2D grid.  In real life, each board square has 2 terrain types (forest/plains), and also one of three elevation levels.  I'm currently using color to represent terrain type.  I'm leaving the center of the square open to show game pieces.  What would an idea be to show 3D elevation 2 dimensionally?

I tried using border thickness, but my CSS is failing me for that with my method of creating the board.  My technical lapse is understanding how to get the borders to display... so help figuring that out would be appreciated.  But the real end state I'm looking to get to is a 2D representation of height.

Sample CSS/Grid is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dxqwy6ge/).

```css
.square {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 11%;
    padding-bottom: 11%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin: .2%;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content
{
    position:absolute;
    height:80%; /* = 100% - 2*10% padding */
    width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 10% 5%;
}
.forest
{
    background-color: rgb(7, 90, 5);
}
.plains
{
    background-color: rgb(245, 238, 136);
}
.hill
{
    border-width: medium;
}
.mountain
{
    border-width: thick;
    border-color: red;
}
.ground
{
    border-width: thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="square forest hill"></div>
        <div class="square plains mountain"></div>
        <div class="square plains ground"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple 3d effect to your squares to simulate layers I would suggest using `box-shadow`.

If you are using multiple layers (as I think you said there are 3 in your game) you can customise `box-shadow` to be different colours, sizes, etc. If you would like to read more about `box-shadow` [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

This is the code I applied to an element: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;` under an HTML/CSS class `layers`.

Code Snippet for example:

*Note: Scroll to bottom of CSS section for added code with comment above it.

```css
.square {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 11%;
    padding-bottom: 11%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin: .2%;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content
{
    position:absolute;
    height:80%; /* = 100% - 2*10% padding */
    width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 10% 5%;
}
.forest
{
    background-color: rgb(7, 90, 5);
}
.plains
{
    background-color: rgb(245, 238, 136);
}
.hill
{
    border-width: medium;
}
.mountain
{
    border-width: thick;
    border-color: red;
}
.ground
{
    border-width: thin;
}

/* THIS IS FOR 3D LAYER EFFECT */
.layers {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="square forest hill layers"></div>
<div class="square forest hill"></div>
<div class="square plains mountain layers"></div>
<div class="square plains mountain"></div>
```

Comment: If you get a chance please mark the question as answered if you felt it to be a satisfactory response and it helped you. @tmptplayer

Comment: Thanks - I was able to tweak this enough to get what I need out of it.  Appreciate the help.